# How to add color in some specific words in a text React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state, background-color

I am developing a text area that contains some specific words(Eg. they can start/end with "%": %QWERTY%). I want these words to have a different color(E.g: Green) and the text area is still editable.
I have tried some solutions but they do not work as I expected, that is why I would like to ask the community how to implement a text input area.

My code is here
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cache-sshmjd?file=/src/TagsInput.js

In the 1st and 2nd inputs, I classified words and used map() to display them in  tags, however, they became separated inputs, not combine into a single one

In the 3rd input, I implemented a  for the special word, but this is a fixed string, and I do not know how to implement it like a state variable to detect any changes in the input area.

Could somebody review my code and help?

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do and for which input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, it colors the target word once the input is no longer focused.

It works by saving the text into state onBlur, separating the string whenever it sees the target word "red".

```
// src/components/TagsInput.js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function TagsInput() {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
  const todoList = [
    { title: "item 1", isDone: false },
    { title: "item 2", isDone: true },
  ];

  function handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.key !== "Enter") return;
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (!value.trim()) return;
    setTags([...tags, value]);
    e.target.value = "";
    console.log("tags: " + tags);
  }

  function removeTag(index) {
    setTags(tags.filter((el, i) => i !== index));
  }
  const onCodeChange = (event) => {
    console.log("onCodeChange: " + event.currentTarget.textContent);
  };

  function TodoItem({ title, isDone }) {
    return (
      <span
        contentEditable="true"
        style={{ color: isDone ? "green" : "red" }}
        value={title}
        onInput={onCodeChange}
      >
        {title}
      </span>
    );
  }

  function Todo(props) {
    const todoList = props.todoList.map((el) => (
      <TodoItem key={el.id} title={el.title} isDone={el.isDone} />
    ));
    return <p className="tags-input-container">{todoList}</p>;
  }
  function ColorfulText({ children }) {
    return <span style={{ color: "green" }}>{children}</span>;
  }

  const [text, setText] = useState(["Your test sentence"]);

  const targetWord = "red";
  // used to split the text at target word but keep the target word
  // in the returned array
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${targetWord})`);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="tags-input-container">
        {tags.map((tag, index) => (
          <div className="tag-item" key={index}>
            <span className="text">{tag}</span>
            <span className="close" onClick={() => removeTag(index)}>
              &times;
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
        <input
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          type="text"
          className="tags-input"
          placeholder="Type something and Press Enter"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <code contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>
          {tags.map((tag) => {
            <span style={{ color: "orange" }}>{tag}</span>;
          })}
        </code>
      </div>
      <Todo todoList={todoList} />

      <div>
        <p
          contentEditable="true"
          style={{ fontSize: "2rem" }}
          onBlur={(e) => {
            setText([...e.target.textContent.split(regex)]);
          }}
        >
          {text.map((words) => {
            if (words === targetWord) {
              return <ColorfulText>{words}</ColorfulText>;
            } else {
              return words;
            }
          })}
        </p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default TagsInput;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Benjamin,
This is absolutely a great solution. 
May I ask you the following questions:

1. Is it possible to add an array of regex in here? 
 const regex = new RegExp(`(${targetWord})`); 

2. The color is changed after the input is no longer focused due to the function onBlur() so is there a way to set the color immediately, I tried onChange() but that did not work?

Comment: Hey Anh, you can use an array by changing the regex to const regex = new RegExp(`(${targetWords.join("|")})`, "ig"); and then see if the word should be highlighted by using if (targetWords.indexOf(words) > -1). The problem here is that when words get deleted, the react app breaks so you'll need to look further into that. Optionally you could also use a library to do this.

Comment: As for changing it onInput, it won't work because the list of words needs to be mapped through to apply highlighting but on every character change, it won't have time to do that. You could try using this https://jsfiddle.net/Gaurav_Kumar_Rana/n5u2wwjg/258819/ not sure how it'll work though with using contentEditable and with it also changing on every input, again